# how to create sql WHERE clause from jqgrid multipleGroup filter condition in ASP .NET MVC2

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

jqGrid multiple group search is used which produces grouped filters object.
ASP .NET MVC2 is used in server side to create where clause string which is passed to PostgreSql.

Oleg ASP.NET MVC jqGrid sample sql where clause builder builds invalid where clause for this condition. It works only without gruping.

Whre to find sample C# code which generates corrent where clause if multipleGroup: true is used ?

```
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {
    savekey: [true, 13],
    multipleSearch: true,
    multipleGroup: true,
    recreateForm: true,
    overlay: 0,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterSearch: true
 });
```

**Edit**

Here is link to WHERE clause builder 
[ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Implementation of searching in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid)

Comment: You're going to need to provide your server side code as well.

Comment: I'm currently using Oleg sample code in server from other answer. This code silently fails (generates invalid where clause) if filter contains multiple grouping. I asked for sample code which works with multiple grouping also generating propert where clause like `WHERE f1=v1 and (f2=v2 or f3=v3)` . Currently it generates only f1=v1 and silently skips `(f2=v2 or f3=v3)` clause

Comment: I have no idea what an "Oleg sample code" is.  You need to provide enough context, just your where clause is not enough.  Edit your answer and don't include this information in a comment.

Comment: I edited question and included link to answer containing downloadable project which fails building multiple grouping WHERE clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [JqGridRequestModelBinder](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc/blob/master/Lib.Web.Mvc/JQuery/JqGrid/ModelBinders/JqGridRequestModelBinder.cs) class which is ASP.NET MVC model binder for jqGrid request, it should give you an idea how to deserialize the multipleSearch/multipleGroup filters. You can find [here](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc/tree/master/Lib.Web.Mvc/JQuery/JqGrid) all the other necessary classes. This is all part of [Lib.Web.Mvc](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc) project. You can find samples on how to use this library [here](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases) (go the zip file or get the latest version from [Subversion](https://tpeczek.svn.codeplex.com/svn)).

Comment: This project does not contain sql WHERE clause builder. Where to find code which builds where clause from search criteria created using multipleGroup: true ? I'm currently using Oleg jqGrid Filter class sample but it silently fails if multipleGroup: true is used

Comment: All the links to the "JqGridRequestModelBinder" and "here" are broken.  Please update the answer with the correct links.

Comment: @Michael Links have changed in the past two years, I've updated them to new ones. Thank you for swift down vote...