# JQGrid Advance Search - Could we use "AND" and "OR" operators at the same time?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid Advance Search feature `multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true`.

I am using Asp.net MVC and classic ado.net + stored procedure also.

Whenever user search data at JGRID, I will pass this searching criteria to stored procedure as parameter values. Such as ...

```
Select * 
From tableName 
Where @WhereClauseDynamic
```

So I have created "Where Clause Generator" Class.

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(GridModelBinder))]
public class JqGrid_Setting_VewModel
{
    public bool IsSearch { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public string SortColumn { get; set; }
    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string Where { get; set; }
}

public class WhereClauseGenerator
{
    private static readonly string[] FormatMapping = {
        " ({0} = '{1}') ",               // "eq" - equal
        " ({0} <> {1}) ",                // "ne" - not equal
        " ({0} < {1}) ",                 // "lt" - less than
        " ({0} <= {1}) ",                // "le" - less than or equal to
        " ({0} > {1}) ",                 // "gt" - greater than
        " ({0} >= {1}) ",                // "ge" - greater than or equal to
        " ({0} LIKE '{1}%') ",           // "bw" - begins with
        " ({0} NOT LIKE '{1}%') ",       // "bn" - does not begin with
        " ({0} LIKE '%{1}') ",           // "ew" - ends with
        " ({0} NOT LIKE '%{1}') ",       // "en" - does not end with
        " ({0} LIKE '%{1}%') ",          // "cn" - contains
        " ({0} NOT LIKE '%{1}%') "       // "nc" - does not contain
    };

    public string Generator(Filter _Filter)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();            

        foreach (Rule rule in _Filter.rules)
        {
            if (sb.Length != 0)
                sb.Append(_Filter.groupOp);

            sb.AppendFormat(FormatMapping[(int)rule.op], rule.field, rule.data);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class GridModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var _WhereClauseGenerator = new WhereClauseGenerator();

            var _IsSearch = bool.Parse(request["_search"] ?? "false");
            var _PageIndex = int.Parse(request["page"] ?? "1");
            var _PageSize = int.Parse(request["rows"] ?? "10");
            var _SortColumn = request["sidx"] ?? "";
            var _SortOrder = request["sord"] ?? "asc";
            var _Where = request["filters"] ?? "";

            return new JqGrid_Setting_VewModel
            {
                IsSearch = _IsSearch,
                PageIndex = _PageIndex,
                PageSize = _PageSize,
                SortColumn = _SortColumn,
                SortOrder = _SortOrder,
                Where = (_IsSearch == false || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Where)) ? string.Empty : _WhereClauseGenerator.Generator(serializer.Deserialize<Filter>(_Where))
            };

        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Filter
{
    [DataMember]
    public GroupOp groupOp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Rule> rules { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Rule
{
    [DataMember]
    public string field { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Operations op { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string data { get; set; }
}

public enum GroupOp
{
    AND,
    OR
}

public enum Operations
{
    eq, // "equal"
    ne, // "not equal"
    lt, // "less"
    le, // "less or equal"
    gt, // "greater"
    ge, // "greater or equal"
    bw, // "begins with"
    bn, // "does not begin with"
    //in, // "in"
    //ni, // "not in"
    ew, // "ends with"
    en, // "does not end with"
    cn, // "contains"
    nc  // "does not contain"
}
```

By using upper code, everything is correct when I search like that

```
{
"groupOp":"AND",
"rules":[{"field":"Seminar_Code","op":"eq","data":"MED01"},
         {"field":"Seminar_Code","op":"eq","data":"CMP05"}],"groups":[]      
}

 sb.ToString() // Output vlaue
 " (Seminar_Code = 'MED01') AND (Seminar_Code = 'CMP05') "
```

So, it is totally correct.

But when it come to more complex search query like that ...

```
{
"groupOp":"AND",
"rules":[{"field":"Seminar_Code","op":"eq","data":"MED01"},
     {"field":"Seminar_Code","op":"eq","data":"CMP05"}],

     "groups":[{
            "groupOp":"OR",
            "rules": [{"field":"Seminar_Code","op":"eq","data":"CMP01"}],"groups":[]}]              
}

sb.ToString() // Actual Output value is like that below
" (Seminar_Code = 'MED01') AND (Seminar_Code = 'CMP05') "
```

But what I had expected is like that below ..

```
" ((Seminar_Code = 'MED01') AND (Seminar_Code = 'CMP05')) OR ( Seminar_Code = 'CMP01' ) "
```

So how could I do it correctly?

Is JQGrid support multiple group operation like "AND" + "OR" ? Is this support only one operator at the same time? Could we use "AND" and "OR" opreators at the same time ?

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is already asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590307/how-to-create-sql-where-clause-from-jqgrid-multiplegroup-filter-condition-in-asp

Comment: @Frank: What kind of access to the database you use? If it is `SqlCommand` with `ExecuteReader` for example then you can generate the WHERE part with parameters like for example `@p1`, `@p2`, `@p3`... instead of the data from `filters`. You can fill the array `SqlParameter[]` during the parsing of the `filters` and use `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange` to include the parameters to the command. Additionally you have to verify that the values of the `field` property of `rule` and `group` are in the list of columns of the table (or query) which you select.

Comment: @Andrus: I forgot about [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590307/how-to-create-sql-where-clause-from-jqgrid-multiplegroup-filter-condition-in-asp). I will take a look at it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all I should mention that I find dangerous the code which you use. You construct the WHERE construction which you want to use in SELECT and you use **trust** the input data. You can receive SQL Injection problem. You should write your code much more safe. You need escape all `[`, `%` and `_` used in operators which contains `LIKE`.

Moreover I would recommend you to use SELECT with parameters. Instead of

```
Seminar_Code LIKE 'MED01%'
```

you can use

```
Seminar_Code LIKE (@p1 + '%')
```

and use [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) to define the value of `@p1` and other parameters which you use.

Now I try to answer on your main question. The definition of `Filter` class which you use don't use `groups` part on the input. You should extend `Filter` class to something like

```
public class Filter {
    public GroupOp groupOp { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> rules { get; set; }
    public List<Filter> groups { get; set; }
}
```

You should also extend the code of the `WhereClauseGenerator.Generator` method to analyse the `groups` part. I recommend you additionally to use names more close to the standard name conversion. If you use the names like `_Filter` for the variable and not for the private members of the class it make the code misundertandable. Moreover the class `WhereClauseGenerator` can be static (`public static class WhereClauseGenerator`) and the method `Generator` too.

The simplest code which add support of the `groups` part of `Filter` can be

```
public static string Generator (Filter filters) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder ();

    if (filters.groups != null && filters.groups.Count > 0)
        sb.Append (" (");

    bool firstRule = true;
    if (filters.rules != null) {
        foreach (var rule in filters.rules) {
            if (!firstRule)
                sb.Append (filters.groupOp);
            else
                firstRule = false;

            sb.AppendFormat (FormatMapping[(int)rule.op], rule.field, rule.data);
        }
    }

    if (filters.groups != null && filters.groups.Count > 0) {
        sb.Append (") ");

        foreach (var filter in filters.groups) {
            if (sb.Length != 0)
                sb.Append (filter.groupOp);
            sb.Append (" (");
            sb.Append (Generator (filter));
            sb.Append (") ");
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString ();
}
```

**UPDATED**: I have to modify the above code to produce correct results for more sophisticated `filters` input:

```
public class Filter {
    public GroupOp groupOp { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> rules { get; set; }
    public List<Filter> groups { get; set; }
}

public class Rule {
    public string field { get; set; }
    public Operations op { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}

public enum GroupOp {
    AND,
    OR
}

public enum Operations {
    eq, // "equal"
    ne, // "not equal"
    lt, // "less"
    le, // "less or equal"
    gt, // "greater"
    ge, // "greater or equal"
    bw, // "begins with"
    bn, // "does not begin with"
    //in, // "in"
    //ni, // "not in"
    ew, // "ends with"
    en, // "does not end with"
    cn, // "contains"
    nc  // "does not contain"
}

public static class WhereClauseGenerator {
    private static readonly string[] FormatMapping = {
        "({0} = '{1}')",               // "eq" - equal
        "({0} <> {1})",                // "ne" - not equal
        "({0} < {1})",                 // "lt" - less than
        "({0} <= {1})",                // "le" - less than or equal to
        "({0} > {1})",                 // "gt" - greater than
        "({0} >= {1})",                // "ge" - greater than or equal to
        "({0} LIKE '{1}%')",           // "bw" - begins with
        "({0} NOT LIKE '{1}%')",       // "bn" - does not begin with
        "({0} LIKE '%{1}')",           // "ew" - ends with
        "({0} NOT LIKE '%{1}')",       // "en" - does not end with
        "({0} LIKE '%{1}%')",          // "cn" - contains
        "({0} NOT LIKE '%{1}%')"       // "nc" - does not contain
    };

    private static StringBuilder ParseRule(ICollection<Rule> rules, GroupOp groupOp) {
        if (rules == null || rules.Count == 0)
            return null;

        var sb = new StringBuilder ();
        bool firstRule = true;
        foreach (var rule in rules) {
            if (!firstRule)
                // skip groupOp before the first rule
                sb.Append (groupOp);
            else
                firstRule = false;

            sb.AppendFormat (FormatMapping[(int)rule.op], rule.field, rule.data);
        }
        return sb.Length > 0 ? sb : null;
    }

    private static void AppendWithBrackets (StringBuilder dest, StringBuilder src) {
        if (src == null || src.Length == 0)
            return;

        if (src.Length > 2 && src[0] != '(' && src[src.Length - 1] != ')') {
            dest.Append ('(');
            dest.Append (src);
            dest.Append (')');
        } else {
            // verify that no other '(' and ')' exist in the b. so that
            // we have no case like src = "(x < 0) OR (y > 0)"
            for (int i = 1; i < src.Length - 1; i++) {
                if (src[i] == '(' || src[i] == ')') {
                    dest.Append ('(');
                    dest.Append (src);
                    dest.Append (')');
                    return;
                }
            }
            dest.Append (src);
        }
    }

    private static StringBuilder ParseFilter(ICollection<Filter> groups, GroupOp groupOp) {
        if (groups == null || groups.Count == 0)
            return null;

        var sb = new StringBuilder ();
        bool firstGroup = true;
        foreach (var group in groups) {
            var sbGroup = ParseFilter(group);
            if (sbGroup == null || sbGroup.Length == 0)
                continue;

            if (!firstGroup)
                // skip groupOp before the first group
                sb.Append (groupOp);
            else
                firstGroup = false;

            sb.EnsureCapacity (sb.Length + sbGroup.Length + 2);
            AppendWithBrackets (sb, sbGroup);
        }
        return sb;
    }

    public static StringBuilder ParseFilter(Filter filters) {
        var parsedRules = ParseRule (filters.rules, filters.groupOp);
        var parsedGroups = ParseFilter (filters.groups, filters.groupOp);

        if (parsedRules != null && parsedRules.Length > 0) {
            if (parsedGroups != null && parsedGroups.Length > 0) {
                var groupOpStr = filters.groupOp.ToString();
                var sb = new StringBuilder (parsedRules.Length + parsedGroups.Length + groupOpStr.Length + 4);
                AppendWithBrackets (sb, parsedRules);
                sb.Append (groupOpStr);
                AppendWithBrackets (sb, parsedGroups);
                return sb;
            }
            return parsedRules;
        }
        return parsedGroups;
    }
}
```

Now the you can use static `ParseFilter` method of the static class `WhereClauseGenerator` like

```
var filters = request["filters"];
string whereString = request["_search"] && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(filters)
    ? WhereClauseGenerator.ParseFilter(serializer.Deserialize<Filter>(filters))
    : String.Empty;
```

Please don't forget that the problem with SQL Injection still exist. I can't fix it till I don't know which kind of database access you use.

Comment: This answer works only if subgroup is specified in advanced search dialog. If advanced search dialog does not contain soubgroup or toolbar search is used it crashes since filters.groups is null . How to fix this?

Comment: @Andrus: Which `filters` data follows to the problem? Coul you post the example? Probably one need just add `if (filters.rules !== null)` and `if (filters.groups !== null)` before the usage in the loop?

Comment: if customer name is typed to search toolbar or grouping is not used in advanced search dialog, filters `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Customername","op":"cn","data":"ok-soft"}]}` is generated. In this case where should also generated. Using if will not generate where clause.

Comment: @Andrus: like I wrote before one need just add additional test for `filters.groups != null` in the code. See updated version of the answer.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I posted also related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053415/how-to-deserialize-jqgrid-multiple-group-search-criteria-in-asp-net-mvc2

Comment: jqgrid can pass search criteria like `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Nimi","op":"cn","data":"a"}],"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[]}]}` If advanced search dialog this query looks OK to use and can created by user intuitevely. However invalid sql is generated. How to change it so that this query works ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: Sorry, I don't use Java.

Comment: @Oleg Can you provide the same in Javascript format ? i.e. javascript converts the query string and parse to the server.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If you want to generate fragment of SQL statement on the client side and send it to the server it will be wrong design. In the way you will produce code with [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The server should not trust the input from the client.

Comment: @Oleg Then what can I do at server side such that is parse the request json data and parse them.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: I don't use Java, but I know that [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) (see also [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)) or other can be used for example.