# how to deserialize jqgrid multiple group search criteria in asp .net mvc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, serialization, jqgrid

If multiple grouping is used, jqgrid advanced search can generate search criteria like

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Nimi","op":"cn","data":"kk"},{"field":"Nimi","op":"cn","data":"kkk"}],"groups":[]}]}
```

Trying to de-serialize it in ASP .NET MVC2 using

```
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var filtersList = serializer.Deserialize<Filter>(_filters);


class Filter
{
    public GroupOp groupOp { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> rules { get; set; }
    public List<Filter> groups { get; set; }
}

class Rule
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public Operations op { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}

enum GroupOp
{
    AND,
    OR
}

enum Operations
{
    eq, // "equal"
    ne, // "not equal"
    lt, // "less"
    le, // "less or equal"
    gt, // "greater"
    ge, // "greater or equal"
    bw, // "begins with"
    bn, // "does not begin with"
    @in, // "in"
    ni, // "not in"
    ew, // "ends with"
    en, // "does not end with"
    cn, // "contains"
    nc  // "does not contain"
}
```

returns empty filtersList.rules property

How to get correct rules from this data ?

**update**

filter

```
    {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Nimi","op":"cn","data":""},
{"field":"Nimi","op":"cn","data":""},{"field":"Nimi","op":"cn","data":""}],
"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[]},{"groupOp":"AND","rules":
[{"field":"Nimi","op":"cn","data":""}],"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],
"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[]},{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],
"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[]},{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[]}]}]}]}]},{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Nimi","op":"cn","data":""}],"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Nimi","op":"cn","data":""},{"field":"Nimi","op":"cn","data":""}],
"groups":[]}]},{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[]},{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[]},{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[]},{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[]}]}]}]}
```

using code from updated part in referenced answer still generates invalid where

```
    ((klient.Nimi ILIKE ('%' || E'' || '%') ESCAPE '!')AND(klient.Nimi ILIKE
 ('%' || E'' || '%') ESCAPE '!')AND(klient.Nimi ILIKE ('%' || E'' || '%') ESCAPE '!'))AND
((((klient.Nimi ILIKE ('%' || E'' || '%') ESCAPE '!'))AND(((((())))AND(((klient.Nimi ILIKE ('%' || E'' || '%') ESCAPE '!'))AND(((klient.Nimi ILIKE ('%' || E'' || '%') ESCAPE '!')
AND(klient.Nimi ILIKE ('%' || E'' || '%') ESCAPE '!'))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem that the code

```
const string filters = "{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[]," +
    "\"groups\":[{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[" +
        "{\"field\":\"Nimi\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"kk\"}," +
        "{\"field\":\"Nimi\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"kkk\"}],\"groups\":[]}]}";

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var filtersList = serializer.Deserialize<Filter>(filters);
```

produce the `filtersList` where `filtersList.rules` is empty list. It corresponds to the input data which you has. On the other side the `filtersList.groups` part is not empty. The `filtersList` from the above code will produce the `Filter` object which equivalent to the following direct initializing:

```
var filtersList = new Filter {
    groupOp = GroupOp.AND,
    rules = new List<Rule>(0),
    groups = new List<Filter> {
        new Filter {
            groupOp = GroupOp.AND,
            rules = new List<Rule> {
                new Rule {field = "Nimi", op = Operations.cn, data = "kk"},
                new Rule {field = "Nimi", op = Operations.cn, data = "kkk"}
            },
            groups = new List<Filter>(0)
        }
    }
};
```

If one parse the information from the `filtersList` one can get at the end still the `WHERE` statement like the following

```
(Nimi LIKE '%kk%') AND (Nimi LIKE '%kkk%')
```

see the code of UPDATED part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10052736/315935) for example. To be exactly the code from the answer produces `((Nimi LIKE '%kk%')AND(Nimi LIKE '%kkk%'))` which is practically the same.

Comment: I tried updated part. For empty filter `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[],"groups":[]}` it returns null

Comment: @Andrus: Is it not correct? To be exactly it is `new Filter { groupOp = GroupOp.AND, rules = new List<Rule> (0), groups = new List<Filter>(0) };`. So it is exactly like your input data. What deserialized value you expect for the input?

Comment: I updated question and added testcase which returns invalid where clause using UPDATED part from  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10052736/315935

Comment: @Andrus: I agree now that you should modify the code more to have no constructs like `(((())))`.

Comment: this search condition is sent by jqgrid. How to modify your code to support empty filters?

Comment: @Andrus: It's much more easy to modify my code where I am the owner of the code. :-) But before all I'll have breakfast...

Comment: @Andrus: I updated the code one more time. The main problem was the usage of `Capacity` property of the `StringBuilder` instead of `Length` property. I added additional code which reduce a little the number of brackets in the resulting WHERE string. The code changes are not required.

Comment: thank you. It worked. If advanced search dialog height is greater than screen height, bottom rules and buttons are not visible and not accessible. How to enable scrollbar in advanced searc dialog if required ?